# Responsive height for Background-Size Image CSS

Tags: css, media-queries, background-image

I have a responsive background image with the following properties

```
    background: url( '@{sitePath}/main_banner.png') center no-repeat;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
    height: 475px;
    background-size: contain;
```

The image needs to be able to scale down (as it does currently) but without a massive height (475px) for smaller devices. 100% min & standard height do not work and I want to avoid specifying individual heights for different media queries if I can help it.

Does anyone know how I can make this effectively responsive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have put static height: 475px; If you want to have smaller height on smaller device try using media queries:

```
@media (max-width: size-that-you-want){
    .class-name{
        width: some-number;
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I am not sure of the answer but I don't think you have read the question correctly because this certainly isn't right